# Get bl_info/version of own addon

Tags: python, blender, add-on

I want to access my addon version as stored in `bl_info` programatically, because I don't want to have duplicates of something that is meant to change.

I tried using `addon_utils.addons_fake_modules`, but that list is empty in background (`--background` command line argument) mode, which I'm interested in using.

I also tried `from .__init__ import bl_info` but results were inconsistent across Blender versions and with/without background mode.

Answer (score 2):

Since importing `__init__` caused issues for some reason, but importing other modules was fine, I made `__init__` export the `bl_info` version itself.

In `__init__.py`:

```py
def register():
    util.addon_version = bl_info['version']
```

In `util.py`:

```py
def get_addon_version():
    # this is set in __init__
    return addon_version
```

Of course using `util` as a name isn't mandatory, nor is using a `get_addon_version()` getter function. I used a getter to make future changes easier.